# django-allauth: submitting form after social login

Tags: django, django-allauth

The current flow for visitors with django-allauth is if the visitor fills in a form, if they are not already authenticated they are shown a login modal with option of facebook login or standard signup form, with the original form data being saved in `ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS=SignupForm`

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):

    def signup(self, request, user):
        new_user = Profile()
        new_user.user = user
        new_user.save()

        # if form data provided with signup save it.
        model = self.cleaned_data['model']
        if model:
           # save the form
```

This works fine if the user signs up using the standard signup form, but if they signup using facebook social account the values from the form are now empty strings i.e. `self.cleaned_data['model']`. I assume the original request object is destoryed so the post data is lost? There also doesn't seem anyway to pass the form data to facebook and receive it back e.g.

`<a title="{{provider.name}}" href="{% provider_login_url provider.id modal="1" process="login" next=request.path scope=scope auth_params=auth_params %}"`

Is the only way to do what I want is to save the form data using local storage or the database then somehow assign it back to the visitor once registered and save it?

Answer (score 0):

What I've gone with is changing the Facebook signup button to link to an intermediate view where I save the form data as session data and then redirect back to the allauth facebook login url.

I then extract the form data from the session in the signup method after the user has authenticated with facebook.